# Include external CSS in an Angular library by modules

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass

I am working on an angular design library based on bootstrap, similar to `ng-bootstrap`

I currently created multiples modules for each design component that can be imported separately based on user needs.

ex :

```
src/
  modules/
    inputs/
    buttons/
    navs/
    tooltips/
    ....
```

Each module can be imported independently and used in application.

The problem I face is with bootstrap scss. Has explained [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#importing) we can import all bootstrap with

`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

or by chunk

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

I would like each of my modules to import their specific `scss` files. The table would import the tables `scss`, the navs the navs etc...

Since bootstrap files are `scss` they need to be compiled before added to the page, and the easy solution of manually adding in each module a `stylesheet` element would not work.

In `ng-bootstrap` they require users to manually add each bootstrap scss that they wish to use, but this could be kind of a pain for users since they need to manually add a module and the associated styles.

Are there any solution to bind a scss file to a module, and compile it if that module is used in the app ?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow in the footsteps of Angular Material's implementation and provide users of your library instructions on how to include the design library styles default styles or custom styles. Take a look at Angular Materials build code and the corresponding exported assets made available as an NPM package. Essentially to manually import a single SCSS file per module that is imported as described above a user would need to take the following steps and understand the styles will be applied globally. There is no dynamic inclusion and compilation of SCSS in Angular upon loading of a module the chunks under the hood would need to be recompiled and the styles would be preprocessed again.

In `angular.json` under the "build.options" object modify "styles" and "stylePreprocessorOptions" and update the configuration to point to the new global styles directory "entry" such as `"styles":["src/styles/styles.scss"], "stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [ "styles" ] }` then in `styles.scss` import your bootstrap scss. Under the styles directory you can now create a custom directory structure and the angular compiler will be able to find everything imported in the global "styles.scss" file. Further reading: read about the shadow DOM in Angular in the context of styles applied based on view encapsulation for component scoped styles vs. globally applied styles.